# How can I choose more than one item from a tableview in JAVAFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I tried this code to get one selected item

```
public class sample implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> list;
    public void Select(){
        ObservableList<String> selected =list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        for (int i =0; i<selected.size();i++)
            System.out.println(selected.get(i));


    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        list.getItems().addAll(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
        list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    }
}
```

But this returned one element, I need to choose more than one. The output is like shown:

[image]

Comment: Set the mode of the selection model to `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`. Then use the `getSelectedItems()` or `getSelectedIndices()` methods of the model. These methods return `ObservableList<T>` and `ObservableList<Integer>`, respectively.

Comment: I did this but still the same


    
    private ListView<String> list;
    public void Select(){
        ObservableList<String> selected =list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        for (int i =0; i<selected.size();i++)
            System.out.println(selected.get(i));


    }

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        list.getItems().addAll(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
        list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    }
@Slaw

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Done @Slaw, I hope it clear now

Comment: In your image the GUI indicates you've only selected one item so of course `getSelectedItems()` will only return a single-element list. You have to select all the items you want first, either with the mouse (e.g. `Shift+Click`) or programmatically via the [`MultipleSelectionModel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html) API.

Comment: I tried to select more than one without Shift+Click it didn't work.
Besides, I tried to choose the one element and the last element using Shift+Click, it chose all between, I mean even row number 2 selected 
@Slaw

Comment: That's what  `Shift+Click` is supposed to do (standard UI behavior). If you want to select more than one item individually, rather than as a range, use `Ctrl+Click` (may not be `Ctrl` if not using Windows).

Comment: I see, thank you very much @Slaw